# RobotFramework- PUT Request throws a 400 error code - "errorCode":"HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error:

Tags: json, robotframework, put, payload

```
Put Json String
    [Documentation]  Verify json string
        ${json_string}=    catenate
         ...    {
         ...              "cloudProvider": "aws",
         ...              "modifiedBy": "abc",
         ...              "interceptCACertChain": "",
         ...              "name": "example",
         ...              "aws": {
         ...                "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE",
         ...                "secretAccessKey": "example",
         ...                "keyARN": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:89123:key/hsjdhsd",
         ...                "signingAlgorithm": "RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256"
         ...              }
         ...            }

       ${data}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${json_string}""")    json
       ${js_string}=    Evaluate    json.dumps($data)    json
       log to console  \n${js_string}\n
       &{header}=  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json
       ${resp}=    API.Put Key Data  ${awsCustomerID}  ${awsKeyID}  ${js_string}  headers=${header}
       log to console  ${resp}
       log to console  ${resp.text}
```

I receive the following error:

```
{"statusCode":400,"errorCode":"HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.broadcom.cloud.smc.dto.CustomerKeyDto` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('data={\"cloudProvider\": \"aws\", \"modifiedBy\": \"abc\", \"interceptCACertChain\": \"\", \"name\": \"example\", \"aws\": {\"accessKeyId\": \"EXAMPLE\", \"secretAccessKey\": \"example\", \"keyARN\": \"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:89123:key/hsjdhsd\", \"signingAlgorithm\": \"RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256\"}}'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.broadcom.cloud.smc.dto.CustomerKeyDto` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('data={\"cloudProvider\": \"aws\", \"modifiedBy\": \"abc\", \"interceptCACertChain\": \"\", \"name\": \"example\", \"aws\": {\"accessKeyId\": \"EXAMPLE\", \"secretAccessKey\": \"example\", \"keyARN\": \"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:89123:key/hsjdhsd", \"signingAlgorithm\": \"RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256\"}}')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"}
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the value of `${js_string}` to see if it's exactly what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes, here's what ${js_string} looks like - {"cloudProvider": "aws", "modifiedBy": "abc", "interceptCACertChain": "", "name": "abc", "aws": {"accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE", "secretAccessKey": "example", "keyARN": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:89123:key/hsjdhsd", "signingAlgorithm": "RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256"}}

Comment: When I take a look at the log file, I see that the put request sends this as the body:       PUT Request : url=https://example.com/v1/customers/aws1/keys/aws1 
 path_url=/v1/customers/aws1/keys/aws1 
 body="data={\"cloudProvider\": \"aws\", \"modifiedBy\": \"abc\", \"interceptCACertChain\": \"\", \"name\": \"example\", \"aws\": {\"accessKeyId\": \"EXAMPLE\", \"secretAccessKey\": \"example\", \"keyARN\": \"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:89123:key/hsjdhsd\", \"signingAlgorithm\": \"RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256\"}}"